# Временной промежуток

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Укажите пожалуйста на мою ошибку. я хочу чтобы точки создавались с промежутком в 5 сек и было видно четко расстояние между ними , вот мой код:

```js
 var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.addEventListener('mousemove' , function(event){
         setTimeout(createDots(event), 5000);     //задержка в 5с
} , false);

function createDots(event){
    var dots = document.createElement("div");
    dots.classList.add('dots')
    dots.style.left = (event.pageX - 20 ) + "px"
    dots.style.top = (event.pageY - 20 ) + "px"
    container.appendChild(dots);
   if(container.childNodes.length > 10){
       container.removeChild(container.childNodes[0])  
   }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #f2dede;
    position: relative;
}
.dots{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;     
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: у вас две проблемы. во первых вы не передаете в `setTimeout` функцию. вы вызываете ее (у вас там есть скобки и аргумент, т.е. функция вызывается, а не передается ссылка на нее). поэтому точки рисуются постоянно при движении. Во вторых таймаут тут в принципе не нужен. надо просто при создании точки запоминать время создания, и далее при движении мыши проверять, прошло уже 5 сек, или нет. Если прошло, то добавляете новую.

Comment: Если не сложно. Можете это оформить в коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таймаут тут в принципе не нужен. При создании точки необходимо запоминать время создания, и далее при движении мыши проверять, прошло уже 5 сек, или нет. Если прошло, то добавляете новую

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
const timeout = 1000; //ms
var last = (new Date()).getTime() - timeout;

container.addEventListener('mousemove' , function(event){
     var n = (new Date()).getTime();
     if(n - last >= timeout){
         createDots(event);
         last = n;
     }
} , false);

function createDots(event){
    var dots = document.createElement("div");
    dots.classList.add('dots')
    dots.style.left = (event.pageX - 20 ) + "px"
    dots.style.top = (event.pageY - 20 ) + "px"
    container.appendChild(dots);
   if(container.childNodes.length > 10){
       container.removeChild(container.childNodes[0])  
   }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #f2dede;
    position: relative;
}
.dots{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;     
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень познавательно.